# SQL Server database audit selects, failed logins and executed code for entire database, all objects

Tags: sql-server, database, audit, sql-server-2016

I want to track all failed logins to our production environment.

Including all selects to all objects.

Based on:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-audit-magic-without-a-wizard/

and

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-security-audit-basics/

and in particular:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sreekarm/2009/01/05/auditing-select-statements-in-sql-server-2008/

It suggests I need to name each object, in the schema for me to be able to save all the select statements, which I don't want to do. There are 1500 tables, and 2300 views.

Is it not possible for the audit, to take the database object, and any SELECT executed on that object is saved in the audit file, including user, statement and time etc.?

The failed login i get from the failed login principal group, but so far I've not been able to get the select statement, unless I specifically name the objects for which to audit.

Naming them, also means I have to update the audit every time a new view or table is added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extended Events

For your specific scenario,you might want to select `batch starting` and `batch completed` events..

[image]

You can also add more info in the next screens like username,host info ...

finally,you can add filters to filter this only for one database or all databases or proc with speficic name and a lot..

This info can be logged to file for later analysis..

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-extended-events-in-sql-server-2012/

For Failed logins,you can right click server and go to below page to audit ..this will be enabled by default and it will be logged to error log

[image]

Comment: Extended sessions are only for the session. Im interested in ongoing auditing of the system, for selects and failed logins/succesfull logins.

I don't see Extended sessions as something that solves? 

From reading the guide, its aimed at one-time investiations, similar to the trace or profiiler.

Comment: @Tommy:can you elaborate

Comment: @Tommy:using selecting batch started and completed events,helps you audit all select statements.For failed logins,i thought you don't need it.but you can see the updated