# How can I do dml auditing on SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, database

Is there any way to do auditing for DML on sql server ??

Appreciate the help that I can get since there is a problem with data that I need to figure out which user that do manipulate the data on various tables , so need to activate the dml audit to include all of the tables in my schema or if possible the database

Regards,

Comment: Do you want to track the data changes or the statements/queries executed?

Comment: create a Database Audit Specification.

Comment: you can use extended events as well from sql2012:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222187/sql-server-database-audit-selects-failed-logins-and-executed-code-for-entire-da/42222511#42222511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that I fogot to mention that we have sql server 2008 , so I found that most of the features were introduced to 2012 and above , so the solution found is:
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION referring to the link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280404.aspx

Regards,

thank you all